# C# - Log4Net for a DLL does not work inclient PC

Tags: c#, dll, log4net

I'm developing a DLL in C# that needs to use Log4Net (I know a DLL shouldn't log itself but it's what they ask for..)

When I execute the code in my PC all logs are created by Log4Net and everything works fine. The problem comes when I perform the same action in a client PC. My code works fine but Log4Net doesn't create any of the log files.

In "AssemblyInfo.cs" I have this line of code:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

In "App.config" I have the following code:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="D:\DebugLog.log" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <!--<rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />-->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %type.%method - %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>        
    
    <appender name="TestDataLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="D:\TestDataLog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %type.%method - %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>    
    
    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <!-- If the following line is not included the log file 
      will not be created even if log4net is configured with this file. -->
      <appender-ref ref="DebugLog" />
    </root>
    
     <!-- To create TestLog -->
    <logger additivity="false" name="TestDataLog">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TestDataLog" />
    </logger>    
  </log4net>
```

Any idea/solution about what it's happening?
Thanks

Comment: does the app have permission to write to the root of D: drive? Does D: drive exist?

Comment: Activate self-logging and have a look at the output.

Comment: _" The <log4net> element supports the following attributes:
debug - Optional attribute. Value must be either true or false. The default value is false. Set this attribute to true to enable internal log4net debugging for this configuration. "_

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Yes D: drive exists and has permission